# Invalid IPA: the .app must be in a "Payload" problem when trying to submit iOS app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

There were no problems during the unity 3d building. Xcode generated the archive correctly too. The problem appeared when sending to apple.

Submitting an application for moderation

Answer (score 0):

I spent several hours on this problem. The solution turned out to be simple. I've run **out of disc space**. More precisely, there were about 1 gigabyte free, but apparently this is not enough. It's a shame that at no stage did the assembly or shipment fail with a message about insufficient hard disk space.